# .htaccess URL rewrite with one and two query string vars

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying URL re-writing for the first time and I have the following URLS which need rewriting:

```
http://domain.com/resorts.php?countryname=Portugal
http://domain.com/rss.php?destination=Torremolinos&itemtype=rfamily
```

I've written the following in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /countryname/(.*)/ resorts.php?countryname=$1
RewriteRule /destination/(.*)/itemtype/(.*)/ rss.php?destination=$1&itemtype=$2
```

But when I try the following, I keep getting URL not found. Please can someone point out what I may be doing wrong? Many thanks in advance.

```
http://domain.com/countryname/Portugal
http://domain.com/destination/Torremolinos/itemtype/rfamily
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule countryname/(.*)/? resorts.php?countryname=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule destination/(.*)/itemtype/(.*)/? rss.php?destination=$1&itemtype=$2 [NC,L]
```